# How to disable number keys on keyboard?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Like I want to use the Textfield only for text only, not numbers. So how to disable that?**

```dart
          title: TextField(
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          controller: searchController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Search for staff name',
              hintStyle:
                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              filled: true,
              enabled: true,
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.person_pin,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 30,
              ),
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: emptyTheTextformfield,
              )),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r"[a-zA-Z]+|\s")),
                ],
```

Comment: the whitelisting for the old version.. currently its use as filtering but thanks for your help :)